# How to find large files and specific file types?

Tags: amazon, amazon-cloud-drive

I've tried different options in the search bar and searched Google far and wide but can't find help. My unlimited Amazon Drive account has been discontinued so I'm trying to prune it of all the large files and videos.

Is there a way I can search for files of a specific file type (like "type:nef") or greater than a certain size?

Comment: Today, this question was bumped by the Community user. Researching Amazon Drive, a notice was shown to me on top of Amazon Drive saying, "Starting December 31, 2023, Amazon Drive will no longer be supported".

Answer (score -1):

Find files by size
On your computer, go to drive.google.com.
At the left, under storage, click your storage.
Example: 13.4 GB of 15 GB used.​
To reverse the sort order, at the top right, click Storage used.

for more search options [check out](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

Comment: This question is about Amazon Drive not about Google Drive.

Answer (score -1):

Download all the files to your local computer and then use an application built for this? For mac eg http://www.derlien.com/. It'll show you big files visually and makes it really easy to clean them up. Does that help?

Comment: This is not practical and, in many cases, is not even feasible for someone with unlimited storage on a cloud storage service.